# Python - Replacing a word in a string with the same word in title-case using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have the following string. I am using re.sub() to replace specific words/patterns from a list in my string. However, I want to capitalize/title-case these replacements in their original form.

```
mystring = "hello foo and bar. You are foo bar"
mywords = ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

desired output:

```
"hello Foo and Bar. You are Foo Bar"
```

What I have tried:

```
new = re.sub(rf"({'|'.join(mywords)})", string.capwords(r"\1"), mystring, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

new2 = re.sub(rf"({'|'.join(mywords)})", (r"\1").title(), mystring, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Tried using Capwords, title, and upper but none will change the casing of the original word. Is it possible to do this with re.sub()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `lambda` in replacement:

```
>>> print ( re.sub(rf'({"|".join(mywords)})',
    lambda m: m.group(1).title(), mystring, flags=re.I) )

hello Foo and Bar. You are Foo Bar
```